# Prohibit Windows users from creating open shares with anonymous login/access

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

Is there a way (using GPO or registry key) to block a windows users when they attempts to create an open share which allow anonymous login/access ?

thank you.

Comment: A standard user in AD should not have the rights to create a share. Only Administrators & System Operators can create shares I believe. You should lower their rights and remove them from those user groups (local & ad)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754359(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Ok thank you #Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 for you response, but it is possible to disable only file sharing with anonymous login ?

Comment: @TMR_OS what you are allowing/restricting would be considered a big security issue. Even if you deny anon access share creation, you should not allow anyone the ability to create shares whenever they want. You should go over your company policy concerning this...